# Pass parameter to stored procedure som retrieves data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that retrieves data, the procedure gets 2 parameters as string.

This procedure is getting called multiple times with new parameters each time.

I would like to call the procedure just one time and send all parameters as a list of parameters.

This is what I have tried

```
create type dbo.adressAndCity as table
(
    [adress] string,
    [city] string
)
go

create procedure dbo.selectItems
(
    @Items  adressAndCity  readonly
)
as
begin
     select * 
     from dbo.testTable
     // the syntax below is nOt correct
     where adress = (@Items.adress) And city = (@Items. city)
end
```

How to access the values inside the parameter table?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Added `sql-server` and `tsql` tags based on the syntax being used.

Comment: You access the values in a table-parameter the same way you access the values in a table.

Comment: @TabAlleman exemple ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a `JOIN`:

```
create procedure dbo.selectItems
(
@Items  addressAndCity  readonly
)
 as
begin
    select T.* from dbo.testTable T
    INNER JOIN @Items I
      ON T.address = i.address) 
     And T.city = I.city)
end
```

Note that I have corrected your misspelling of `address`

Comment: how to access them inside "where statment"